# Flutter requires Android SDK 28 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I have a problem with installation, the Flutter. I set all the parameters, following the official flutter guide, but I have this error:

[image]

I installed Android sdk, this is my configuration:

[image]

[image]

I also set the flutter environment variable.
What's missing?
Thank you
E.

Answer (score 0):

Your build tools don't show a version number, and you can update them to v29. To do so, click on the "-" icon, it will turn into a check icon. Then hit "apply".